# Associated prime ideals of $D[[X]]$

Tags: commutative-algebra, power-series

Let $D$ be an integral domain.

A prime ideal $P$ of $D$ is called an *associated prime* of a principal ideal $aD$ of $D$ if $P$ is minimal over $(aD:bD)$ for some $b\in D\setminus aD$. For brevity, we call $P$ an associated prime of $D$.

My question is:

If $P$ is an associated prime of $D$, is $P[[X]]$ also an associated prime of $D[[X]]$?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $P$ is an associated prime of $D$. Then there $P$ is minimal over $(aD:bD)$ for some elements $a$ and $b$ of $D$. ''If  $D[[X]]$ is a flat $D-$module, by a well-known result of N. Bourbaki, $(aD:bD)D[[X]]=(aD[[X]]:bD[[X]])$''. Now, is $P[[X]]$ minimal over $(aD[[X]]:bD[[X]])$?